# Writing To A Range Using VBA array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have a script that pulls the first cell value of a table from a database and adds it 10 times. I want to write that list to excel.

Here's what I have so far:

```
sub x()
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim i As Variant

    myArray = Sheets("License Plate Number").Range("LP")
    myVariable = (Trim(Right(mp_start, 12)))

    For i = 0 To (ord_qty / 120) - 1

        Myarr = "MP" & myVariable + i
        myArray = Myarr

        'MsgBox Myarr
        Debug.Print Myarr

    Next i

end sub
```

How can I write to a range using VBA?

Comment: If variables had sensible names, it would be much easier to understand the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple. You just do it like this.

```
Range("A1:J1")=Myarr
```

Comment: I did it just repeat the last number over

Comment: @TerranceMatthew That is because your `myArray` is not an array. It only contains the last value because you overwrite the entire contents of the variable on each loop iteration.